# Create linked server from SQL Server 2008 to Intersystems Caché

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do
>   you want to keep the linked server?
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "NRAD". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server
>   "NRAD" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified". (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 7303)

Please help me on this......

Comment: You should really read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that you have provided a DSN name to OLE DB Adapter for ODBC Data Sources that does not exist. Make sure you have installed the InterSystems ODBC Client Driver and set up a working DSN first on the same machine as the MS SQL Server. If you believe you have set up a valid DSN, figure out which driver manager you set it up in and which driver manager SQL Server is accessing. On 64-bit Windows there is a 32-bit and a 64-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator (the driver manager) and they don't share DSN's.

If none of what I suggest above solves the problem, contact InterSystems' Support department and they will help you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Now the issue is, how to fetch database and table names from intersystem cache database, even i dont know the name of databases or tables, only i have the cache.dat file of intersystem cache database